# Why is this ring Cohen-Macaulay?

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

> Let $q_1, q_2$ be quadratic homogeneous polynomials in $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ over $\mathbb C$ and let $X_i:=V(q_i)=\{(a_0,\dots,a_4)\in \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^4\mid q_i(a_0,\dots,a_4)=0\}$. If $X_1\cap X_2$ is a surface, then $R=\mathbb{C}[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]/(q_1,q_2)$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

I can't understand about Cohen-Macaulay ring well. Please let me know why it is CM.

Comment: @user121097: The intersection being a surface implies that they do not have a common factor.

Answer (score 0):

Any [complete intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_intersection) is Cohen-Macaulay. Since a surface in $\mathbb{P}^4$ cut out by two polynomials is a complete intersection (4 - 2 = 2), it is automatically CM.

Comment: Note: the surface is in $\mathbb{P}^4_{\mathbb{C}}$. Also, one should be careful to distinguish between set-theoretic and scheme-theoretic complete intersections (as well as the difference between being CM and ACM).

Comment: @zen: Thanks for comment. Regarding your last sentence, is it simply a worry that the resulting "surface" might not be reduced? I believe reduced is part of being a surface.

Comment: The definition of "surface" will depend on who you talk to - in any case, the question could have been much clearer in my opinion if the OP were more specific (by the way, my handle is zCn)